# firebase admin sdk uses ssl on storage emulator

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

I passed STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:9199 and STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST=127.0.0.1:9199 via environment var to the docker container. In both cases the admin sdk tries to connect to the storage emulator using https

> FetchError: request to https://localhost:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/ ..... failed, reason: write EPROTO 139925863208896:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

i am using "firebase-admin": "11.8.1"
edit: got the same with 11.11.0

am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

change STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST=127.0.0.1:9199 to STORAGE_EMULATOR_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:9199 . If the protocol is missing it adds https, causing the issue.

Comment: Damn, thank you so much for this... such a bizarre error and there is no one talking about it on those hundreds of firebase storage issues.